# Attempting to load class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver - Spring boot - takes forever to load / startup (hours) but eventually does

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, digital-ocean

- Spring boot 1.5.8
- Java 1.8
- Mysql 5.7.23
- OS: Centos 7
- Host: Digital Ocean
- Apache

I've been banging my head against the wall on this one. Seems like one day all of a sudden my app started taking forever to load (hours and hours), not sure why. I did try to install [rocket.chat](https://rocket.chat/docs/installation/manual-installation/centos/) (node/mongodb/etc) and it seemed around that time things went south but I think that is just a coincidence.

I enabled logging

```
logging.level.com=DEBUG 
logging.level.org=DEBUG
```

Did some things I saw on some posts like

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
```

And installed [haveged](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/fresh-tomcat-takes-loong-time-to-start-up)

Nothing worked. Does work great on my local machine, but on the server, takes sooooo long to load.

Here is what I got in my logs. Things fly for about 3 seconds in the log, and then hits here and stops.

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk/bin/java -jar /var/myjar-1.1.2.jar SuccessExitStatus=143
```

I am trying to paste this log into a code snip it but it isn't working...

```
2018-09-05 17:37:39.560 DEBUG 7970 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder'
2018-09-05 17:37:39.560 DEBUG 7970 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating instance of bean 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder'
2018-09-05 17:37:39.560 DEBUG 7970 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
2018-09-05 17:37:39.560 DEBUG 7970 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration'
2018-09-05 17:37:39.561 DEBUG 7970 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'jpaVendorAdapter'
2018-09-05 17:37:39.561 DEBUG 7970 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating instance of bean 'jpaVendorAdapter'
2018-09-05 17:37:39.561 DEBUG 7970 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
2018-09-05 17:37:39.561 DEBUG 7970 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration'
2018-09-05 17:37:39.642 DEBUG 7970 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      : Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2018-09-05 17:37:39.689 DEBUG 7970 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection    : Instantiating driver using class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver [url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydbname?useSSL=false]
2018-09-05 17:37:39.690 DEBUG 7970 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ClassLoaderUtil     : Attempting to load class[com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] from org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@65b54208
2018-09-05 17:39:47.377 DEBUG 7970 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection    : Instantiating driver using class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver [url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydbname?useSSL=false]
2018-09-05 17:39:47.377 DEBUG 7970 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ClassLoaderUtil     : Attempting to load class[com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] from org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@65b54208
2018-09-05 17:40:39.080 DEBUG 7970 --- [Engine[Tomcat]]] org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase  : Start expire sessions StandardManager at 1536187239079 sessioncount 0
2018-09-05 17:40:39.080 DEBUG 7970 --- [Engine[Tomcat]]] org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase  : End expire sessions StandardManager processingTime 1 expired sessions
```

If I need to turn on more debugging, let me know.

Comment: Does it completely load (eventually)? I suspect the DNS resolution on your server is causing timeouts looking up your connection IP so disable with [skip-name-resolve](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-name-resolve). Otherwise is the dataset or server differently configured on your local machine? Consider enabling and looking at the [slow query log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html) too.

Comment: Yeah it does load eventually, but takes forever, and I have to restart apache too... odd...